# Error in reading bmp header C++ (number of color = 0)

Tags: c, header, bmp

First, sorry for my English, i'm French. Then thank you if you can answer my question.
I've got a project where i have to read a bmp file. This is my header:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



#pragma pack (1)
typedef struct {
char         filetype[2];  
unsigned int filesize; 
short        reserved1;
short        reserved2;
unsigned int dataoffset;    
} file_head;



typedef struct {

unsigned int headersize;
unsigned int width;
unsigned int height;
short        planes;
short        bitsperpixel;  
unsigned int compression;  
unsigned int bitmapsize; /*taille de l'image*/
unsigned int horizontalres;
unsigned int verticalres;
long  NumColorsUsed;
unsigned int importantcolors;
} bmp_head; 


#pragma pack (0)
}
```

And this is my main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/*#include <errno.h> bibliothèque erreur*/
#include <string.h>
#include "Header.h"



void main() 

{

FILE *input; /*fichier d'entree*/
FILE *output; /*fichier de sortie*/
bmp_head *bmp_header;
file_head *file_header;
rgb **pointcolor= NULL;
rgb *col;
char* data;
int n;
int i; 
int j;
int B;
int a;

input = fopen("Rouge.bmp", "rb"); /* ouverture du fichier lena se trouvant dans le dossier du projet*/
if (input == NULL) 
{       printf("Erreur lors de l'ouverture! \n");
} 
else  
{       printf("Fichier ouvert!\n");


}
file_header=NULL;
file_header = (file_head*)malloc(sizeof(file_head));
if (file_header == NULL)
{
    printf("Erreur lors de l'allocation file_header!\n");
}
else
{   
    printf("Allocation de file_header reussie!\n");
}

n = fread(file_header, sizeof(file_head), 1, input); 
if (n < 1)
{
    printf("Le fichier ne peut pas etre lu !\n");
}
else
{   
    printf("La lecture du fichier a reussi!\n\n");
    }


bmp_header= NULL;
bmp_header = (bmp_head*)malloc(sizeof(bmp_head));

if (bmp_header == NULL)
{
    printf("\nErreur lors de l'allocation bmp_header!\n");
}
else
{   
    printf("\nAllocation de bmp_header reussie!\n");
}

n = fread(bmp_header, sizeof(bmp_head), 1, input); 
if (n < 1)
{
    printf("\nLe fichier ne peut pas etre lu !\n");
}
else
{   
    printf("\nLa lecture du fichier a reussi!\n");

    printf("Le nombre de couleurs est %d\n", bmp_header->NumColorsUsed); 

}

system("pause"); 
fclose(input);

free(input);
free (bmp_header);

}
```

My problem is in the last line (before system("pause"): when i try to read my number of color, they say 0.
Does someone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: Fyi, `%d` is wrong for a `long`. it should be `%ld`. And I believe zero is an allowable value for the number of colors in the color table. It means default to 2^N, where N is the bits per pixel.

Comment: Zero is a valid value for the number of colours. If the bitmap uses a palette, it means the maximum number. If the bitmap has a colour depth of 16 or more, the bitmap doesn't use a palette and there is no number of colours. (The pixel rgb values are written into the file directly.) [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Comment: Oh, and don't `free` the file handle. It is enough to `fclose` it.

Comment: Thank you ! Ok so 0 is a normal value! And how can i have pixel by pixel the value rgb?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the bitmap header is:

```
typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER{
        DWORD      biSize;
        LONG       biWidth;
        LONG       biHeight;
        WORD       biPlanes;
        WORD       biBitCount;
        DWORD      biCompression;
        DWORD      biSizeImage;
        LONG       biXPelsPerMeter;
        LONG       biYPelsPerMeter;
        DWORD      biClrUsed;
        DWORD      biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;
```

Your definition is different.

The definiton of the file header is:

```
#include <pshpack2.h>
typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
        WORD    bfType;
        DWORD   bfSize;
        WORD    bfReserved1;
        WORD    bfReserved2;
        DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER, FAR *LPBITMAPFILEHEADER, *PBITMAPFILEHEADER;
#include <poppack.h>
```

With:

```
typedef unsigned short      WORD;
typedef unsigned long       DWORD;
```